# VBA open .pdf after export from Excel with specified Zoom level

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, charts, excel-charts

I save active sheet as `.pdf` file with `OpenAfterPublish:=True` option, can I pass additional parameter which specify `zoom` level with which this pdf will be opened (my default is Acrobat Reader) ?

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    SOMENAME, Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False _
    , OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it is possible to save it with a specific zoom to pdf.
However, the best workaround I may think of is to do the following:

In Acrobat Reader set the default Zoom to the one you want it like this:

```
Edit>Preferences>Accessibility>Override Page Display
```

Comment: can I set some properties of activesheet which will influence the zoom size with which AR opens pdf ?

Comment: As far as I know - nope. But if you find a way, I would be interested to know it as well, so please tag me in it :)

Comment: The only way I have found is to manually change the position of your chair.